# PnP Powershell Install-PnPApp

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

I have a question about "Install-PnPApp" command.

I have Pnp Powershell script in Azure function and I am connection using an Azure Active Directory registered application,

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -ClientId $appId -Thumbprint $thumbprint -Tenant $tenant
```

In the next step i wanna Install app from tenant catalog:

```
Get-PnPApp -Identity .... | Install-PnPApp
```

It doesn't give me error, but when i go to site collection, then I see the app is being installed, but it stays in "Installing" step, it never complete installation.

Is it possible to use Install-PnPApp if I connect with Azure Active Directory registered application?

Thank you, Matjaz Reberc

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I registered an Azure AD Application:

```
Register-PnPAzureADApp -ApplicationName SPSitesSelected -Tenant xxxx.onmicrosoft.com -Store CurrentUser -Username "xxxx@XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com" -Password (Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Enter Password")
```

[image]

[image]

And connected **`PnP PowerShell`** by using the below command:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/Test-site" -ClientId "8e1a3301-e5be-XXXXXXXXX" -Thumbprint "34FB3B3F1E586D2BA4638E20XXXXXXXX" -Tenant "XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com"
```

[image]

Check whether **`Get-PnPApp`**,returns null response:

[image]

**`Get-PnpAzureADApp -Identity *****`** returns the Azure AD Application:

[image]

Please check **`Get-PnPApp`** results any response, if yes, then try executing the below commands and check if it resolves the issue.

```
Install-PnPApp -Identity XXXXXXXX -Scope Site

Get-PnPApp -Identity XXXXXXXX -Scope Site | Install-PnPApp
```

***If still the issue persists***, check whether you have required permissions to install the PnP Application.

**Reference:**

[Install-PnPApp | PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Install-PnPApp.html)

Comment: Hello Rukmini, thank you for you help. I found out thet the problem is not PowerShell script, but in the App. I tried to install some other App and it worked. The problem seems to be how the App is "Addet" to SP App Catalog. In App catalog, if the App has "Not applicable" status in "Added to all sites" then I can not install it in site collection with AAD registerd application. I can manualy install app or I can install app if I use "Connect-PnPOnline" with username / password.  Thank you, Matjaz